# SQL Sum MTD & YTD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have only just started looking into SQL.

I have a SQL Server 2008 r2 database that will return two fields DocDate & InvValue. I need to sum the InvValues as MTD & YTD as of Today's Date  So it looks like

```
**Period** ///////  **Total value**
MTD        ////////////111111.11
YTD       /////////////999999.99
```

I have done a fair amount of Googling and can do one or the other with SUM & DATEPART, but I am stuck with trying to do both.

Can someone give me some pseudo-code that would help me google a little further.

Thank you @Gordon Linoff, That helped a lot and I learned something, That I will find useful in the future.
My code now looks like:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(T1.[DocDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN T0.[TotalSumSy] END) AS YTD,
SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(T1.[DocDate]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(T1.[DocDate]) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN T0.[TotalSumSy] END) AS MTD

FROM [dbo].[INV1] T0 INNER JOIN [dbo].[OINV] T1 ON T1.[DocEntry] = T0.[DocEntry]
```

However I now get

```
YTD.........MTD
99999.99....111111.11
```

And I need

```
YTD........99999.99
MTD........11111.11
```

Any further assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  Period = 'MTD',
  Total_value = SUM(T0.TotalSumSy) 
FROM dbo.INV1  T0 
  INNER JOIN dbo.OINV  T1 
     ON T1.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry
WHERE 
    T1.DocDate >= DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010101')
  AND 
    T1.DocDate < DATEADD(month,1+DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010101')

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'YTD', 
  SUM(T0.TotalSumSy) 
FROM dbo.INV1  T0 
  INNER JOIN dbo.OINV  T1 
     ON T1.DocEntry = T0.DocEntry
WHERE 
    T1.DocDate >= DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010101')
  AND 
    T1.DocDate < DATEADD(year,1+DATEDIFF(year,'20010101',GETDATE()),'20010101') ;
```

The (complicated) conditions at the `WHERE` clauses are used instead of the `YEAR(column) = YEAR(GETDATE()` and the other you had previously, so indexes can be used. WHen you apply a function to a column, you make indexes unsuable (with some minor exceptions for some functions and some verios of SQL-Server.) So, the best thing is to try to convert the conditions to this type:

```
column <operator> AnyComplexFunction()
```

Comment: Thank you @ypercube. Can you explain more about the Where clause. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when year(docdate) = year(getdate()) then InvValue end) as YTD,
       sum(case when year(docdate) = year(getdate()) and month(docdate) = month(getdaate())
                then InvValue
           end) as MTD
from table t;
```

This assumes you have no future dates in the table.  If you do, add in `docdate < getdate()` to both clauses.

EDIT:

If you need this in two rows, you can simply do this:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then 'YTD' else 'MTD' end) as which,
       (case when n.n = 1 then YTD else MTD end) as value
from (select sum(case when year(docdate) = year(getdate()) then InvValue end) as YTD,
             sum(case when year(docdate) = year(getdate()) and month(docdate) = month(getdaate())
                      then InvValue
                 end) as MTD
      from table t
     ) cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) n;
```

Comment: Thanks you. Added additional info to my request.