# calculate year-to-date and month-to-date and compare the year-to-date sales and month-to-date in mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to calculate year-to-date and month-to-date and compare the year-to-date sales and month-to-date and sales trends respectively w.r.t about 1000 customers in our report, Please let me know if there are  api  readily available in mongodb-3.2,  as we are having approx 50 million of sales data in Mongodb -3.2. The documents are in this format :

```
{"customerName":"C1", "transactionDate":"2000-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":1000, "companyName":"D1"}
 {"customerName":"C2", "transactionDate":"2000-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":2000, "companyName":"D2"}
{"customerName":"C3", "transactionDate":"2000-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":3000, "companyName":"D3"}
{"customerName":"C1", "transactionDate":"2001-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":4000, "companyName":"D1"}
{"customerName":"C2", "transactionDate":"2001-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":5000, "companyName":"D2"}
{"customerName":"C3", "transactionDate":"2001-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":6000, "companyName":"D3"}
{"customerName":"C1", "transactionDate":"2002-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":5000, "companyName":"D1"}
{"customerName":"C2", "transactionDate":"2002-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":4000, "companyName":"D2"}
{"customerName":"C3", "transactionDate":"2002-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":3000, "companyName":"D3"}
{"customerName":"C1", "transactionDate":"2003-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":2000, "companyName":"D1"}
{"customerName":"C2", "transactionDate":"2003-01-01", "unitsSold":100,"revenue":1000, "companyName":"D1"}
```

The expected output for year 2003 w.r.t. company names :

```
{"year":2003:"companyName":"D1", "totalRevenue":3000, "prevyear":2002,"lastcompanyname":"D1","trends":(2000+1000 - 5000) /5000 * 100 = -40}
{"year":2003:"companyName":"D2", "totalRevenue":0, "prevyear":2002,"lastcompanyname":"D2","trends":(0-4000)/4000 * 100 = -100 }
{"year":2003:"companyName":"D3", "totalRevenue":0, "prevyear":2002,"lastcompanyname":"D3","trends":(0-3000)/3000 * 100 = -100 }
```

and so on , so on for year 2002 and

We have to calculate year to date, month to date , quarter to date  sales and trends w.r.t. company names.
We have to also calculate year to date, month to date , quarter to date  sales and trends w.r.t. customer  names.

Please lemme know how to do this calculation using mongodb-java / mongodb / spring-data-mongodb api.
Regards
Kris

Comment: Just a starting point. Something on the lines : db.orders.aggregate([{"$project":{_id:0,revenue:1,companyName:1,date:{"$substr":['$transactionDate',0,4]}}},{$group:{_id:{companyName:'$companyName',date:'$date'},rev:{$sum:'$revenue'}}},{$sort:{'_id.companyName':1,'_id.date':1}}]). This will produce an output like { "_id" : { "companyName" : "D1", "date" : "2000" }, "rev" : 1000 }. The rest you can do it in your application.

Comment: I want a single query which solves the problem, as we are having around 50 million docs, running 2 or more queries, and comparing 1000 customers with pre-dated, severely kills performance.Kris

Comment: Thanks @IshanSoni, can you please look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786302/sql-sum-mtd-ytd , and try to show how to do the same in mongodb 3.2. Regards, Kris